# How to install MySQL-python with SSL support via setuptools?

Tags: python, mysql, ssl, setuptools

After installation, I can connect to a regular MySQL database, but not to ones with SSL - for the later I get the following error:

```
File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/MySQLdb/__init__.py" in Connect
  74.     return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/MySQLdb/connections.py" in __init__
  170.         super(Connection, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs2)

Exception Type: NotSupportedError at /shop/free_license/
Exception Value: client library does not have SSL support
```

Inside my `setup.py`. I have

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    ...,
    install_requires = [ 'MySQL-python == 1.2.2' ], 
    dependency_links = [
        'http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/mysql-python/mysql-python/1.2.2/MySQL-python-1.2.2.tar.gz?r=http%3A%2F%2Fsourceforge.net%2Fprojects%2Fmysql-python%2Ffiles%2Fmysql-python%2F1.2.2%2F&ts=1370248965&use_mirror=surfnet',
    ]
)
```

This fails even if I try to install 1.2.4 without specifying dependency_links.

I have header files installed `sudo apt-get install libssl-dev`

My versions are:

```
$ uname -a
Linux devzsoldosp 2.6.32-33-generic #72-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jul 29 21:07:13 UTC 2011 x86_64 GNU/Linux
$ python
Python 2.6.5 (r265:79063, Oct  1 2012, 22:04:36)
[GCC 4.4.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import setuptools
>>> setuptools.__version__
'0.6c11'
>>>
```

The virtualenv was initialized with the `virtualenv testsetuptools` command. When the database connection was installed via `sudo apt-get install python-mysqldb # 1.2.2-10build1`
, the same mysql version, SSL connections work on the same machine.

What else do I need to do to be able to move to a setuptools based install?

Answer (score 0):

Verify your mysql client supports SSL:

```
mysql --ssl --help
```

And the same for the server:

```
mysql -u root -p
mysql> show variables like "%ssl%";
```

Follow the instructions to set-up a secure connection: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/ssl-connections.html

Here is more info on how to create an SSL connection to MySQL using the Python library: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-connectargs.html

There is an issue in python-mysqldb 1.2.3-1build1: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/python-mysqldb/+bug/1027075

Comment: thanks for the answer! As said, the mysql side of things is OK, and so is running the same sample code through the global, ubuntu-installed python-mysqldb package. I'll take a look at the 1.2.3 build, but since I'm using the older version, my initial assumption is that is not the issue (but will doublecheck, I've been wrong before :))